# How to spread for loop target list across multiple lines

Tags: python, for-loop, multiline

I'm having trouble with unpacking a large number of variables from list of tuples. How can I make the unpacked variables span multiple lines?

I want to change

```
for t,a,f,b,s,x,j,p,w,q in results:
    print(t,s,x)
```

to

```
for t,a,f,b,s,x,
    j,p,w,q in results:
    
    print(t,s,x)
```

Comment: @Brian Why did you remove the information that "the actual variable names are a lot longer"? That's no good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option (with round brackets):

```py
for (t, a, f, b, s, x, 
     j, p, w, q) in results:
    print(t, s, x)
```

Comment: I like this a lot more because of the brackets make it super clear

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\` at the end of each line, to spread your python code across the multiple lines.

```py
for t,a,f,b,s,x, \
    j,p,w,q in results:
    
    print(t,s,x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just ask [Black](https://black.vercel.app/). When you have something actually too long for one line (i.e., like your *"the actual variable names are a lot longer"*, not like your question's example which doesn't show the issue), it uses parentheses.